# background image not displayed with css

Tags: html, css

I want to set background image and it is not working.
I dont know what the problem is but it just not working please help me out.

html code is:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header clearfix">
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-header">


        <a href="" title="Home" class="ann"><div class="logo"></div></a>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

My css is:

```
.logo{
background: url("img/logo.png") no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
width: 201px;
margin-left: 10px;
height: 76px;
margin-top: 19px;
transition:all .3s;
-webkit-transition:all .3s;
-moz-transition:all .3s;
-ms-transition:all .3s;
-o-transition:all .3s;
}
```

And my image size is 231*86px hope u will find the answer and post it

Comment: here's a fiddle that's working fine using your code, I just changed the background url: https://jsfiddle.net/wpsmbxuu/ what issue are you having?

Comment: Maybe your other CSS is overriding this, because it is more specific.

Comment: learn something about browser devtools

Comment: I'm testing it on my WAMP server

Comment: And it was not working tried all possible things

Comment: @AbdulAhmad If I'm getting the image from my image library and also make that image so no user can copy my icon image from the website make it hidden if some one search in my image library

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad we we apply logo to the website as i have done through css any other person can look at my css and can copy my logo image from the directory of my website i want that when the user try to go to the url in which my image is kept he will not able to locate my image.

Comment: hmm.. I'm sorry but I don't know if thats possible, or how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `http://` before the image locating in your webserver like this `http://img/logo.png` and it will start working.